# Bitcoin split payment API? (Adaptive Split Payment)

Tags: payment, payment-processors, micropayments

Currently our site works with "stripe marketplace" and we trying to also implement bitcoins.

I would like to know that Bitcoins API can give me a split payment service?

For example: From buyer to seller and to us (3%) all at once. All instant without holding money.

Any alternatives?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/111678/ ?

Comment: Yes and no. I read it, but don’t really understand where to start

Answer (score 1):

Alice is buyer, Bob is seller and Carol manages the marketplace in this example.

```
bitcoin-cli createwallet "W1"
{
  "name": "W1",
  "warning": ""
}

bitcoin-cli createwallet "W2"
{
  "name": "W2",
  "warning": ""
}
```

Alice(W1) and Bob(W2) update their public keys in the marketplace for an order:

```
"address": "tb1qadr842f467n2hdvg579knxn396jlvq2q6as6d4" (Alice)

"pubkey": "03217c1f9fe975bbc9f2fdfdd6e4247179f188dbb8d53861eef3782b1649cd4a39"


"address": "tb1q3ykxvwdaf9ddue9m8zsgxw4p6lev438djdayly" (Bob)

"pubkey": "021424787d68460022599d058866251192ea2abe7778781946687e6d0076511822"
```

One new public key for Carol is automatically added to each order:

```
tb1qlm6k7sg5yl0xjujppsmmee25pdwramjq370f93 (Carol)

"pubkey": "03e9a3f746b6fe9a334e79309867ec964d89ef31be9518d6f50bf207dc5788e93a"
```

2of3 multisig address is created using the above 3 keys when an order is executed:

```
bitcoin-cli createmultisig 2 "[\"03217c1f9fe975bbc9f2fdfdd6e4247179f188dbb8d53861eef3782b1649cd4a39\",\"021424787d68460022599d058866251192ea2abe7778781946687e6d0076511822\",\"03e9a3f746b6fe9a334e79309867ec964d89ef31be9518d6f50bf207dc5788e93a\"]"
{
  "address": "2N9pimWivhqQx2mKYL4arE6YB15HtGrc7hZ",
  "redeemScript": "522103217c1f9fe975bbc9f2fdfdd6e4247179f188dbb8d53861eef3782b1649cd4a3921021424787d68460022599d058866251192ea2abe7778781946687e6d00765118222103e9a3f746b6fe9a334e79309867ec964d89ef31be9518d6f50bf207dc5788e93a53ae",
  "descriptor": "sh(multi(2,03217c1f9fe975bbc9f2fdfdd6e4247179f188dbb8d53861eef3782b1649cd4a39,021424787d68460022599d058866251192ea2abe7778781946687e6d0076511822,03e9a3f746b6fe9a334e79309867ec964d89ef31be9518d6f50bf207dc5788e93a))#scwqjskc"
}
```

Alice sends 0.01 BTC to multisig address `2N9pimWivhqQx2mKYL4arE6YB15HtGrc7hZ` for this order: https://mempool.space/testnet/tx/a061d35e6ca82b7622d33afb1d4ee4d0a7a93125fefa6394fdba6f35c72c14d9

This multisig address should be imported in Bitcoin Core wallets (W1 and W2) used for signing PSBT:

```
bitcoin-cli importmulti '[{"desc" : "sh(multi(2,03217c1f9fe975bbc9f2fdfdd6e4247179f188dbb8d53861eef3782b1649cd4a39,021424787d68460022599d058866251192ea2abe7778781946687e6d0076511822,03e9a3f746b6fe9a334e79309867ec964d89ef31be9518d6f50bf207dc5788e93a))#scwqjskc","timestamp" : "now","label" : "test", "watchonly": true}]'
```

A release transaction is created to spend funds sent to multisig earlier with 2 outputs (one belongs to Bob and other to Carol):

```
bitcoin-cli createpsbt "[{\"txid\":\"a061d35e6ca82b7622d33afb1d4ee4d0a7a93125fefa6394fdba6f35c72c14d9\",\"vout\":1}]" "[{\"tb1qnh8vju93xxrv7fw25l49d8lkzjgl9v02q4ppfu\":\"0.008\"},{\"tb1qxm27rdc6yu7ne4fvxx5yv4k0l4gxqq7x575xe8\":\"0.001\"}]"

cHNidP8BAHECAAAAAdkULMc1b7r9lGP6/iUxqafQ5E4d+zrTInYrqGxe02GgAQAAAAD/////AgA1DAAAAAAAFgAUnc7JcLExhs8lyqfqVp/2FJHyseqghgEAAAAAABYAFDbV4bcaJz081SwxqEZWz/1QYAPGAAAAAAAAAAA=
```

Alice signs the transaction in W1 wallet:

```
bitcoinc-cli walletprocesspsbt "cHNidP8BAHECAAAAAdkULMc1b7r9lGP6/iUxqafQ5E4d+zrTInYrqGxe02GgAQAAAAD/////AgA1DAAAAAAAFgAUnc7JcLExhs8lyqfqVp/2FJHyseqghgEAAAAAABYAFDbV4bcaJz081SwxqEZWz/1QYAPGAAAAAAAAAAA="


{
  "psbt": "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",
  "complete": false
}
```

PSBT is shared with Bob and he signs it in W2 wallet:

```
bitcoin-cli walletprocesspsbt "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"


{
  "psbt": "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",
  "complete": true
}
```

Carol will finalize PSBT and broadcast the transaction:

```
bitcoin-cli finalizepsbt "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"
{
  "hex": "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",
  "complete": true
}

bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction 0200000001d9142cc7356fbafd9463fafe2531a9a7d0e44e1dfb3ad322762ba86c5ed361a001000000fc0047304402202af6b7295640dab48482f452f30b9dc8c0eb9847d59dea9e1866d151c7c59b1d022004458f0d9134c50ef7751e113070d0046c4ae5e31a35beb13a7a19659d81832e01473044022003bb1b13fac7f61763209dd3e16c85b649fdc4842aeaa59e989682c000d477f402202aaaadd0211f20b20d1e4a6c490d40161c3569ee9903afa6e4dc6378c08bc16d014c69522103217c1f9fe975bbc9f2fdfdd6e4247179f188dbb8d53861eef3782b1649cd4a3921021424787d68460022599d058866251192ea2abe7778781946687e6d00765118222103e9a3f746b6fe9a334e79309867ec964d89ef31be9518d6f50bf207dc5788e93a53aeffffffff0200350c00000000001600149dcec970b13186cf25caa7ea569ff61491f2b1eaa08601000000000016001436d5e1b71a273d3cd52c31a84656cffd506003c600000000

dad03ca8744b4809cadaa903f06a2baa5ae54bedd5bfadcdab14f3761599058d
```

[image: transaction]

https://mempool.space/testnet/tx/dad03ca8744b4809cadaa903f06a2baa5ae54bedd5bfadcdab14f3761599058d

Comment: Does that mean that I also have to create wallet for them? It would mean that they cannot use their existing wallet like on Coinbase or such?

Comment: You won't have to create wallets for them but will need public keys from their wallet. Or else you could improve UI/UX with a browser extension that does everything in the background using Bitcoin Core JSON RPC and website API. Coinbase wallet won't work for any of these things.

Comment: I see. Thanks, at least it gives me some direction

Comment: @FosAvance Note that many (almost all?) wallets will not support the functionality required for this to work (ie, ability to retrieve public keys, and sign multi-sig PSBTs). This scheme would also leave you vulnerable to Alice and Bob completing the payment without paying you your fee (they could coordinate to create a transaction that just pays it back to bob, for example).

Comment: @chytrik both have solutions. 1. Inform and ask the users to use wallets that support PSBT and multisig. Lot of wallets/projects with better UI/UX allow this including some hardware wallets. 2. This is a problem with P2P market which can be managed by creating incentives for users to use the platform for orders instead of settling outside. Example: Reputation, Points, Tokens etc. 3. Hodlhodl manages both issues in a diff way that users are unaware of things involved but still use 2of3 multisig for each P2P trade: https://gitlab.com/hodlhodl-public/hodl-client-js/-/blob/master/multisig-spec.md

Comment: @Prayank right, its theoretically possible, but in a practical sense, **most** users are going to be using crappy wallets that won't have said functionality. A website that is attempting to implement these sort of bitcoin payments should at least be made aware of that here, in case they do a bunch of engineering work and then discover that no bitcoin payments come in because almost none of their users are running the required software.